# Android - Tabhost working in Activity class

Tags: android, android-tabhost

OK, I must be overlooking something silly because I am unable to get my tabhost to display in my Activity class.  I am getting the dreaded force close when I try to run the app.  It will work if i extend TabActivity, **but I can't do that** [see edit below] because once I move the code from my prototype project its going to be in a custom class that inherits from Activity.

Here is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />            
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And here is the class that is trying to create and display the TabHost:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class my_proto extends Activity
{   
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      Log.i(this.toString(), "OnCreate");

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Log.i(this.toString(), "get tab host");
      TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost); 
      host.setup();

      Log.i(this.toString(), "add tabs");
      host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one")
                      .setIndicator("First Results")
                      .setContent(new Intent(this, FirstResultsListViewActivity.class)));

      host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
                      .setIndicator("Second Results")
                      .setContent(new Intent(this, SecondResultsListViewActivity.class)));

      Log.i(this.toString(), "adjust tab size");
      host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 35;
      host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 35;

   }// end onCreate

}// end class my_proto
```

This is the error I get in the log.

```
11-17 16:49:51.271: INFO/com.my_proto.my_proto@43b80b50(1302): OnCreate
11-17 16:49:51.472: INFO/com.my_proto.my_proto@43b80b50(1302): get tab host
11-17 16:49:51.480: INFO/com.my_proto.my_proto@43b80b50(1302): add tabs
11-17 16:49:51.521: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1302): Shutting down VM
11-17 16:49:51.521: WARN/dalvikvm(1302): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-17 16:49:51.530: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my_proto/com.my_proto.my_proto}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:646)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.mc_proto.mc_proto.onCreate(my_proto.java:29)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-17 16:49:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1302):     ... 11 more
```

Its complaining about not calling setup, but I am calling it.  There is another version of setup that needs some kind of LocalActivityMananger.  I have tried replacing the call to setup the call below but no luck.

```
LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
host.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
```

[edit] The call above didn't work so I took it back out.  Although I was getting a new error logged.

```
11-17 20:24:58.382: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my_proto/com.my_proto.my_proto}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created.
```

[edit] Based on some of the comments below I realized I need to be clearer about why I can't inherit from TabActivity.  Once I have the prototype working I need to port this into an existing app's screen that inherits from Activity.  I will need to load the TabHost into a Layout within that Activity.  It will basically be a LinearLayout with a row of status icons, followed my a LinearLayout with the Tabhost in it.  I know that if I can get this working I can move onto the next phase.  Thanks!

```
---------------------------
|      status icons       |
---------------------------
|    Tab, Tab, Tab        |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         | 
---------------------------
|      status icons       |
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  Apparently, `TabActivity` extends `ActivityGroup`, which extends `Activity`.  But in your code your class extends `Activity` which is not an activity group.

So there are two options:

1) If you want the tab content to be activities, have your class extend `ActivityGroup` (instead of `Activity`).  Then your call to setup should be `host.setup(getLocalActivityManager());`

This way you are emulating the `TabActivity` source code.

2) If you can have your tab content be views (vs activities), keep your class as extending from `Activity`, and keep your call to `setup()`.  But for the setContent part do something like this:

```
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
                .setIndicator("Second Results")
                .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

                    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return new TextView(TestActivity.this);
                    }
                }));
```

And then define your list view inside createTabContent (that's usually what I do - I prefer using views instead of activities as the contents of the tabs).

Comment: thanks for all your time.  I'm still not quite there, if you look at my picture above I'm going to need to wedge the tab host into a center pane of a screen whose base class is Activity.  I'm surprised that using LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
host.setup(mLocalActivityManager); doesn't work when using an Activity.  I saw your tutorial on using ListViews in the tabs and I;m going to look that over.  Currently each of my tabs is a ListView, although that won't always be the case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you have a scenario in which you need to use Activity class for your Tabhost you can try the following it works.

```
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost); //here tabHost will be your Tabhost
    LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(mActivity, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(state); // state will be bundle your activity state which you get in onCreate
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
```

Comment: This works and you still keep your activity as a regular activity.

Comment: This worked for me. Although LocalActivityManager is deprecated, this may still be a plausible solution till you switch over to using the Fragments API.

Comment: LocalActivityManager is deprecated

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem: this question helps [Android: TabHost without TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163884/andorid-tabhost-without-tabactivity)

Apparently, you only need to add one line:

```
LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
host.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
```

Answer (score 2):

`android:id="@+id/tabhost"` doesnt work for me. I have to write `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the class to

```
public class my_proto extends ActivityGroup
```

and change the following:

```
this.mHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
this.mHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());
```

It seems ok for me

Comment: ActivityGroup is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Change the class declaration which has this:

```
public class my_proto extends Activity
```

to

```
public class my_proto extends TabActivity
```

Comment: I can't do that.  I stated in my desciption "its going to need to inherit from a custom class that inherits from Activity"

Comment: @cbursk: that was not there when I answered here... that was edited after I posted the answer...

Comment: It was there.  I added the details after your post.  No biggie.

Answer (score 0):

What tommie says is true. You should also look at the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html