# TabHost without TabActivity, ActivityGroup, or LocalActivityManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am creating an app that has three tabs on the main screen.  Each of the tabs I have the content set as separate Activities.  The reason I used activities instead of Fragments is because inside one of the tabs I need to be able to have Fragments and nested Fragments are not supported.

At first, I was extending TabActivity to do so, but then I realized that it is deprecated so then I started looking around.  I found someone suggested using a ActivityGroup here, but... that too is deprecated.

It seems all the solutions on StackExchange to the problem I am having, contain deprecated functionality.  Such as, [Android: TabHost without TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163884/android-tabhost-without-tabactivity) , and [Android - Tabhost working in Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209587/android-tabhost-working-in-activity-class)

What is the correct way to have a TabHost and allow the tabs to contain Fragments without using deprecated functionality?

Below is what I currently have

```
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class HomeTabs extends ActivityGroup {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        LocalActivityManager mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
        host.setup(mlam);

        TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Home");
        spec.setContent(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
        spec.setIndicator("Home");
        host.addTab(spec);

        spec = host.newTabSpec("Browse");
        spec.setContent(new Intent(this, BrowseActivity.class));
        spec.setIndicator("Browse");
        host.addTab(spec);

        spec = host.newTabSpec("About");
        spec.setContent(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
        spec.setIndicator("About");
        host.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Comment: See the `TabActivity` replacement sample shown on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Comment: The replacement sample is extending the FragementActivity and if I use that I wouldn't be able to contain a fragment within the tab content because the tab content itself would be a fragment and you cannot nest them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way to have a TabHost and allow the tabs to contain Fragments without using deprecated functionality?

Put views in the tabs, whether statically in the layout as immediate children of the `FrameLayout` inside the `TabHost`, or dynamically via the variant of `setContent()` that takes a `TabContentFactory`. Those views can, AFAIK, take things that manage fragments (e.g., `ViewPager`), or possibly fragments directly themselves via `<fragment>` elements.

Or, don't use `TabHost`. Use tabs in the action bar, using ActionBarSherlock for backwards compatibility. Or, use a `ViewPager`. Or, use a `ViewFlipper` and a `TabWidget` (which, despite the docs, does not appear to have an actual dependency on `TabHost`). Or, use a `ViewFlipper` and some other control mechanism to switch between "tabs".

Or, get rid of your "fragment within the tab content".