# Working with Tab Control in Mono for Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, xamarin.android, android-tabhost

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209587/android-tabhost-working-in-activity-class) on SO as the problem was similar to mine.

In my main activity, I'm calling a class `TabControl` which extends `ActivityGroup`.

**Please note that I can't extend my main class from `ActivityGroup` as I want to use `Custom_Title` feature which will not be possible with `ActivityGroup`.**

**1). main class :**

```
public class MainActivity: Activity
{
   TabControl _tabControl;
   protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
   {
         _tabControl=new TabControl();
    _tabControl.CreateTabs();
    }
}
```

**2.) TabControl class :**

```
public class TabControl:ActivityGroup
    {
        TabHost tabHost;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {            
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TabView);
        }

    public void CreateTabs()
    {
        try
        {
             tabHost=(TabHost)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabHost);
         LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
             tabHost.Setup(mLocalActivityManager);
             //tabHost.Setup();             

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent; 

        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                spec=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Heat Map");
                spec.SetIndicator("Heat Map");
                spec.SetContent(intent);
                tabHost.AddTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (LiveMkt));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                spec=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Live Mkt");
                spec.SetIndicator("Live Mkt");
                spec.SetContent(intent);
                tabHost.AddTab(spec);

                tabHost.CurrentTab = 1;                 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {}
        }       
    }
```

**3.) TabView.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout">

<TabHost 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp"       
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

**But I'm getting following error :**

```
 Module Name : TabControl

Method Name  : CreateTabs

Exception Details : Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.

at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Android.App.Activity.FindViewById (Int32 id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at StockGadget.Controls.TabControl.CreateTabs () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

--- End of managed exception stack trace ---

java.lang.NullPointerException

at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
```

**As I'm absolute beginner to `Mono for Android`, any help appreciated...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main activity, just create tab control and refer all other activities through it.
Extend the main activity from `TabActivity`.