# How to use two tabHost on Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Below is my layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="#FF888888"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="#FF888888"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

There 2 tabhost in layout l1 and l2.
And below code is mine to use tabhost:

```
TabWidget tw;
TabHost tabHost;
tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent; 
Resources res = getResources();
    tw = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("B", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("C").setIndicator("C", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

But it can only control the tabhost in l1.
How can I do to control the tabhost in l2?

I make some modify as below:

```
    private TabWidget tw;
    private TabHost tabHost;
    private TabWidget tw1;
    private TabHost tabHost1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent; 
        Resources res = getResources();
        tw = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("B", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("C").setIndicator("C", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        tabHost1 = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1;
        Intent intent1; 
        tw1 = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec1 = tabHost1.newTabSpec("D").setIndicator("D", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent1);
        tabHost1.addTab(spec1);

        intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec1 = tabHost1.newTabSpec("E").setIndicator("E", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent1);
        tabHost1.addTab(spec1);

        intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec1 = tabHost1.newTabSpec("F").setIndicator("F", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent1);
        tabHost1.addTab(spec1);
        intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec1 = tabHost1.newTabSpec("G").setIndicator("G", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent1);
        tabHost1.addTab(spec1);
}
```

And error message is below:

```
08-14 16:26:26.960: D/AndroidRuntime(9763): Shutting down VM
08-14 16:26:26.960: W/dalvikvm(9763): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a291f8)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testtwolayout/com.example.testtwolayout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:232)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at com.example.testtwolayout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-14 16:26:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9763):     ... 11 more
```

The line MainActivity.java:68 means line         tabHost1.addTab(spec1);

I have resolve by this [Android: TabHost without TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163884/android-tabhost-without-tabactivity) .
And simple test code as below:

```
    private LocalActivityManager mlam;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tw = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
        Resources res = getResources();



        tabHost =(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(mlam);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent; 

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("B", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        tabHost1 = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
        tabHost1.setup(mlam);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1;
        Intent intent1;


        intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec1 = tabHost1.newTabSpec("C").setIndicator("C", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent1);
        tabHost1.addTab(spec1);

        intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
        spec1 = tabHost1.newTabSpec("D").setIndicator("D", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search)).setContent(intent1);
        tabHost1.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost1.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

And MyGroup is below:

```
public class MyGroup extends ActivityGroup {
    public static ActivityGroup group;  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        group = this;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onBackPressed() {  
        group.getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onBackPressed();  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();  
        Intent it;
        Window w;
        View view;

        it = new Intent(this, AActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
        w = group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("AActivity", it);  
        view = w.getDecorView();  
        group.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

And AActivity as below only show a random number:

```
public class AActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.a);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.atv);
        int x = (int)(Math.random()*42+1);
        String xx = Integer.toString(x);
        Log.d("q", xx);
        tv.setText(xx);

    }
}
```

But I find the left layout's tab 0 will not show number.
But the line Log.d("q", xx); is show.
How about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant get hold of two different tabhosts by using the same **id**. Therefore, you must need to change the **android:id** of your second tabhost.

For example: `android:id="@+id/mySecondTabhost"`

And later you need to use proper `R` class which refers to your package (not *android.R*) in order to retrieve your custom defined **id** value.

Comment: I add code like above. The null exception occurs at line tabHost1.addTab(spec1);.

Comment: Another is @android:id/tabs or android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" cannot be change.

Comment: It will show like this TabHost requires a FrameLayout with id "android:id/tabcontent". message.

Comment: I use this line TabHost tabHost1 = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost1); to second tabhost. Is it error?

Comment: The error same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795677/tabhost-nullpointerexception-when-tabhost-isnt-the-only-thing-in-the-layout this.

Comment: But he change to getTabHost().

Comment: You dont need to change `android:id/tabs` and `android:id/tabcontent`. They are supposed to have the same name. Can you paste your full code and error-stack logs? Otherwise its pretty unclear for me to guess the problem

Comment: I have add at the bottom of question.