# Is it possible to have none of the tabs active in the Tabhost?

Tags: android, menu, tabs

Actually I am using 2 Tabs.Both of the tab is having different activity.Now when I run the application, I want to show some 3rd(any) Activity below the 2 tabs while none of the Tab is active,and this activity will change according to Menu Button.And when a tab is pressed it will show its activity.Again when I will use menu button ,then Tab will become inactive,and menu activity will show again below Tabs.If Yes, then How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you disable/make the tabs when the third activity is shown. Enable the tabs when they are selected or touched or clicked.

Comment: Third Activity Got the Error which is being called from menu though I have already set android:id="@android:id/tabs".....Error is-- Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Comment: Are you trying to extend TabActivity or Activity? If you are extending Activity, then follow these steps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5098774/563306

Comment: I believe you cannot use TabActivity for the third activity because its not in the tabs. You may use Activity, and findViewById(R.id.tabHost) in xml.

Comment: Third one is activity extended.L