# TabActivity -> Fragments.. is it really this complicated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabactivity

I know the tabactivity thing has been covered here a million times, by ten million people.   I've got the developer references and have been reading all the threads I can find on SO.  My question is though, is fragments REALLY that complicated?   From what I can gather, it seems to be, whereas TabActivty was so easy.   See example below:

My current code, required for four tabs, looks like this:

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ServerActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("server")
                .setIndicator("Server",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_server))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StatusActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("status")
                .setIndicator("Status",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_status))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LoggingActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("logging")
                .setIndicator("Logs",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_logging))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DeliveryActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("deliveryqueue")
                .setIndicator("Queue", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_queue))
                // .setIndicator("Delivery Queue",
                // res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
```

According to the developers reference, for the equivelent of 4 tabs, you need ALL this:

```
    import java.util.HashMap;

import com.example.android.supportv4.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

/**
 * This demonstrates how you can implement switching between the tabs of a
 * TabHost through fragments.  It uses a trick (see the code below) to allow
 * the tabs to switch between fragments instead of simple views.
 */
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {
    TabHost mTabHost;
    TabManager mTabManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    /**
     * This is a helper class that implements a generic mechanism for
     * associating fragments with the tabs in a tab host.  It relies on a
     * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
     * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
     * between fragments.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
     * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabManager supplies its own dummy
     * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
     * care of switch to the correct fragment shown in a separate content area
     * whenever the selected tab changes.
     */
    public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final int mContainerId;
        private final HashMap<String, TabInfo> mTabs = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
        TabInfo mLastTab;

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;
            private Fragment fragment;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
            private final Context mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabManager(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, int containerId) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mContainerId = containerId;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(info.fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            mTabs.put(tag, info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);
            if (mLastTab != newTab) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (mLastTab != null) {
                    if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                        ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                    }
                }
                if (newTab != null) {
                    if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                        newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                                newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                        ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                    } else {
                        ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                    }
                }

                mLastTab = newTab;
                ft.commit();
                mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it REALLY that complex? it's like two - three times the amount of code to complete the same thing.   I really want to stay away from using deprecated methods, but wow.

Comment: Yea, I'm disappointed that we have to do that much just to create tabs. As far as I can tell, there isn't really any other way. I hope someone can answer this.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163884/android-tabhost-without-tabactivity/5098774#5098774 This might be what we're both looking for (I can't take a look right now). You can use TabHost without extending TabActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer document's solution is around 100 lines of additional code (plus a view replacement). The solution provided isn't particularly complex, and extendable in an obvious location (**onTabChanged**) if you want to trigger an action when the tab is changed. I wouldn't shy away from using it as it will obtain the results you so desire. I was moving from an ActionBar to TabHost and found it to be a drop-in replacement for my existing fragments management.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Sorry about the late acceptance, been really busy with work. I'll dig around and figure it out, java is still really new to me so some of the stuff covered in the developer guide is a little above my head, but I'm learning!

Comment: Anytime, I hope your path in learning is easy. There's not a lot to fear with Android, and Java is also forgiving. An idle word of advice, using Log liberally will help you out a lot in finding issues.